# Can a minimum cost path of weighted graph be calculated using a BFS in O(n)?

Tags: graph-theory

I am new to Graph Theory . 
We start at node (1,1) and need to reach node (r,c) , ie a rectangle can be imagined with nodes numbered as 2D cartesian plane , we start our search from top-left node and need to reach bottom-right node . Traversing from one node to other has some weight , so Can a minimum cost path of weighted graph be solved using a BFS (Breadt First Search) in O(n) ?If it is not possible with BFS , could you suggest some different algorithm . Thanks before hand .

Answer (score 2):

If you're new, then you should definitely look at [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) which is the most known algorithm and should do what you want. You could tweak a BFS to do it but it would be very slow (and probably do more of less the same as a Dijkstra). Try it out and come back if you have any problems